# Auto Comment for Off Topic -> Minimal Understanding

Tags: feature-request, comments, close-reasons, off-topic, question-quality

When someone votes to close an issue as...

> Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

<sup>subcategory of off-topic</sup>

They see that wonderful list of things to remember.  However, the OP doesn't.  At least, not until the post is closed.

I think having an automatic comment, that says something along the lines of,

> Please check that your question follows the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Would be beneficial to the OP, and give them a (potential) chance to edit their question before it's closed.  I don't know what the reopen rates are, but I believe they're pretty low.

I do think that a nicely formatted FAQ page would have a better effect than the list there.  Bright colors, screenshots, arrows, etc.

Comment: That - or show the (likely) close message to the OP right off the bat, say starting with the 2nd closevote

Comment: I guess that makes just as much sense as "possible duplicate" comments - gives OP extra time to clean up and rewrite, at no real cost.

Comment: @Pëkka  - yep. See [Please allow new users to view close reasons on their questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254211)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Pekka's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188821/auto-comment-for-off-topic-minimal-understanding#comment582081_188821) looks to be a pretty good idea: Once there are multiple close votes of the same type on a question, start showing a box similar to the on hold/closed box with text such as:

> Some members of the community think that this question should be put on hold because it is [reason]. You may want to edit and improve your question so this doesn't happen.
>
> [reason details]

This box would only display to the asker and would trigger a mini-notification on appearance (which is cancelled if it's successfully put on hold).

Comment: @Toomai - why wait for multiple on concurring opinions? Improvement can begin immediately.